# For each from MSDN in C++ CLI using visual studio 2017 yields compile errors

Tags: foreach, c++-cli

I made a blank C++ CLI project in visual studio and copied the [serial port example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#Examples). At first I had to enable CLR, but now it tells me that the "for each" is not valid syntax. I understand that is might have something to do with C++11 or higher, but I have no idea where to change that setting or if it has any affect. 
I read that "for each" is not the best way to iterate, but why is it at the MSDN site anyway?

Here is a minimal example:

```
#using <System.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
int main()
{
    for each (String^ s in SerialPort::GetPortNames())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: C++ CLI and C++ are not the same language. Please tag correctly. Also ideally you should provide a [mcve] and not force people to go through a link

Comment: Thanks Sheep. I'll add the CLI tag and created a minimal example.

Comment: Note that CLI in C++/CLI does NOT stand for `command line interface` but `common language infrastructure`. To make a C++/CLI project (which would have `/CLR` enabled by default) you need to actually create a C++/CLI project. By default VS doesn't have that project type isntalled so you may need to go to the VS installer -> Individual Components -> Compilers, Build Tools & Runtimes -> C++/CLI

Comment: Oh! well, I don't actually want a "cli" application. Just a command line program, but if I disable CLR I can't use the #using <system.dll> anymore.

Comment: Any idea how to make this compile then? Either as a "command line interface", or "common language infrastructure" or both? How am I supposed to run the code from he MSDN page?

Comment: Maybe you should start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6ad605x.aspx

Comment: I did start at that page and have been making console applications since the 90's, so I understand the fundamentals of them. I started a new project using the "windows console application" template, which sounds like the right thing. I'm installing a CLI package for visual studio C++ now. Lets hope this solves something.

Comment: OK. installing the "CLI package for visual studio C++" did the trick. Can now choose the "CLR console application" template which fixes the syntax errors. Thanks for showing me the difference between CLI and CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out that I had to install the CLI package for visual C++ to be able to make a "windows console application" with "common language infrastructure". 
So basically you need the C++CLI package to make a C++CLI/cli application. Confusing!

Comment: This answer doesn't jive that well with "I made a blank C++ CLI project".  Do explain what you actually made.

Comment: Hans, the problem I had (invalid syntax) was solved by installing the CLI package and choosing that as the template. Please explain me why this is a bad question, as well as a bad solution?